# Remove all elements of a set that contain a specific char

Tags: python, set

I have a set of a few thousand primes generated from a generator:

```
primes = set(primegen()) = set([..., 89, 97, 101, 103, ...])
```

Some of those primes have a zero in them. I would like to get rid of them. Is there a way to do this all at once?

Currently I am removing elements as I loop through primes, with a regex match:

```
import re
zero = re.compile('.+0.+') 

while primes:
    p = str(primes.pop())
    if zero.match(p):
        continue
    # do other stuff
```

I think this is the best way, but am curious if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Summarizing and timing the responses:

With the first 100000 primes. (Using timeit and copying the primes set each time)

## root

```
primes = {p for p in primes if '0' not in str(p)}
```

10 loops, best of 3: **29.6 ms** per loop

## Mike

```
while primes:
    p = str(primes.pop())
    if '0' in p:
        continue
    # do other stuff
```

10 loops, best of 3: **38.9 ms** per loop

## Garrett R

```
filter(lambda x: '0' not in str(x), primes)
```

1000 loops, best of 3: **963 µs** per loop

## Kasramvd

```
def zero_membership_checker(num):
    while num:
        if num%10 == 0:
            return True
        num = num / 10
    return False
```

1 loops, best of 3: **6.65 s** per loop

## hiyume

```
import re
zero = re.compile('.+0.+') 

while primes:
    p = str(primes.pop())
    if zero.match(p):
        continue
    # do other stuff
```

10 loops, best of 3: **69.4 ms** per loop

Comment: just fyi, you don't need the list(p) part.  `if '0' in p` will work without the conversion

Answer (score 9):

You could use a set comprehension to filter your existing set of primes.

```
primes = {p for p in primes if '0' not in str(p)}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** I have *absolutely* no idea what you want to do with this or why this would be useful. I just assume that you want to remove numbers like `101` and `103` from your `primes` set because they contain a zero digit.

You don't even need regexes for that. It can be done with a simple list comprehension:

```
# assume that primes is defined
str_primes = map(str, primes)
filtered_str_primes = [p for p in primes if "0" not in p]
filtered_primes = map(int, primes)
```

[Kasramvd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35878029/1071311) might be faster, you shoud test both out.

I'm not sure if your set is just an example or if you plan to use a generator to produce a possibly infinite list of primes. In the latter case, you can use `itertools` to define the filtered sequence lazily (that is, in will only generate the next element when you ask for it instead of consuming the whole list):

```
from itertools import imap, ifilter
filtered_primes = imap(int,
                       ifilter(lambda p: "0" not in p,
                               imap(str, primes)))
```

Wait, I forgot, this should yield the same outcome, but with less code (I'll leave the older solution for completeness):

```
filteres_primes = (p for p in primes if "0" not in str(p))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert the numbers to string and use regex to match the zero in it (or better that it use `in` operator for membership checking), which is an expensive operation specially when you are dealing with large data sets. You can use following function to detect if there is any zero within your number then use it within a set comprehension to preserve the expected numbers:

```
>>> def zero_membership_checker(num):
...     while num:
...         if num%10 == 0:
...             return True
...         num = num / 10
...     return False
... 
>>> s = set([89, 97, 101, 103])
>>> 
>>> {i for i in s if not zero_membership_checker(i)}
set([89, 97])
```

Answer (score 1):

`filter` also works for this application:

```
In [25]: primes = set([83, 89, 97, 101, 103])

In [26]: filter(lambda x: '0' not in str(x), primes)
Out[26]: [89, 83, 97]
```

Here's some timing info, for anyone that's curious

```
In [37]: %timeit filter(lambda x: '0' not in str(x), myList)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.7 ms per loop

In [38]: %timeit {p for p in myList if '0' not in str(p)}
10 loops, best of 3: 22 ms per loop
```